# Getting table value from view to controller

Tags: grails

I have a domain class, Report, with a referenced child class, prompt.

One the edit Report page you are allowed to reorder the order of prompts in a table. Then when the user goes to run the report, on that page the prompts are in said order.

The table on the Report edit.gsp page uses some jQuery to allow drag and dropping of the row, and it updates the display order number, but only on the UI side, nothing is going back to the database yet.

I would like to be able to pass this new order back to my update command, but cannot figure out how to grab the table row data for the life of me.

When searching almost all of the results are how to get data from the controller to the view, not vice-versa.

Here is the snippet of table code

```
<table id="prompts">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>${message(code: 'prompt.name.label', default: 'Name')}</th>
                    <th>${message(code: 'prompt.description.label', default: 'Description')}</th>
                    <th>${message(code: 'prompt.required.label', default: 'Required')}</th>
                    <th>${message(code: 'prompt.displaySeqno.label', default: 'Display Order')}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <g:each in="${reportInstance.prompts.sort{it.displaySeqno}}" status="i" var="prompt">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}" onclick='window.location = "${createLink(controller: "prompt", action: "edit", id: prompt.id)}"'>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: prompt, field: "name")}</td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: prompt, field: "description")}</td>
                        <td>${prompt.required}</td>
                        <td class="displaySeqno">${prompt.displaySeqno}</td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And then in the controller, I tried

```
params.list('displaySeqno')
```

But it would just return an empty array.

How can I get the value of the displaySeqno from within my controller class?

Thanks.

Comment: @doelleri This is already within the form on the page, is that what you mean?

Comment: Then try using inputs ;)

Comment: Data is passed from the view to controller with forms. Forms have inputs. The names and values of those inputs will be mapped to params.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I understand that. But shouldn't there be a way to pass the data from the table rows back to the controller? This table is part of the form, it just isn't an input field.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those time (which happens a lot) where a fundamental understanding of how HTTP / Java EE works would allow you to solve your problem very easily.  Forms or no forms, you have to pass a value into the request that goes to the server for it to end up on the server.  How is this

```
<td class="displaySeqno">${prompt.displaySeqno}</td>
```

ever going to get to the server, form or no form?  The answer is, it is not.  Assuming a typical form post you would need to store the value in a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="displaySeqno" value="${prompt.displaySeqno}" />
```

Then it would make it to the server.  If you're processing with Ajax of some sort, you would need to pass it in as a parameter via the API.  Assuming jQuery, for example:

pseudo code ahead:

```
var params = $('#youFormId').serialize();
$.post('some/url/to/post/to', params, function(data) { 
});
```

Bottom line is, if you want to pass something to the server, you have to provide the means for that to happen.